# Configuration for debugging C program in visual studio code in MacOS

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure my vsc for debugging C program by following the following [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac). However, I am getting this error while compiling the program. Can please kindly advise what is the problems here.

```
Error: there is no registered task type 'cppbuild'. Did you miss to install an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
```

other error
[image]

launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "clang - Build and debug active file",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

task.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
}
```

gcc version

```
steh@u81z08s03 ft_printf % gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: what is the use of the gcc version if you use clang

Comment: in your task you tell clang to use c++17, and then you expect it to treat your program as a C file, you also link `libc++`, does clang use the same error format as gcc

Comment: Thank you.  I will update my launch.json and task.json.